# Convert 2-item list to a dotted pair?

Tags: list

**Q:** how can I convert a 2-item list to a dotted pair `cons` cell?

I can convert a 2-item list to a dotted pair with:

```
(let ((list '(1 2)))
  (cons (car list) (cadr list)))        ; => (1 . 2)
```

I'm blanking: is there a built-in function that does this, or
should I roll my own?

Comment: Shameless plug: [suggest](https://github.com/Wilfred/suggest.el) is great in cases like this. Put your input as `'(1 2)`, your output as `'(1 . 2)` and it will suggest `(apply #'cons '(1 2))` for you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cons` makes a cons cell out of two arguments. `apply` uses a list as arguments to a function.  When their powers combine: `(apply #'cons x)` converts a two element list into a cons cell (without having to poke around inside the list) *and* raises an error if the list isn't 2 long.

Comment: It's awesome how this is both more concise and includes proper error handling.